# Touching a multiple plotsymbol in core plot and get the two touch plot symbol index

Tags: ios7, core-plot, xcode5.1

I want to get the difference between two points touched simultaneously. But i am only getting one index into scatter plot by this method,

```
-(void)scatterPlot:(CPTScatterPlot *)plot plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx withEvent:(CPTNativeEvent *)event;
```

How to get two index by multitouch?

Answer (score 0):

The built-in interaction methods only support one point at a time. You can get the coordinates of the touch points, convert them to the coordinate space of the plot area layer, and use the `-indexOfVisiblePointClosestToPlotAreaPoint:` method to get the index of each point from the scatter plot.